# sudoedit Command not found issue in Linux machine

Tags: sudo

There is sudo version 1.6.7p3 installed in our Linux machine. But when I execute "sudoedit", it shows "command not found". May I know why this is happening? What is the way to make sudoedit work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your linux distribution? `sudoedit` should come with `sudo`, however, considering how old ([circa. 2003](https://www.sudo.ws/pipermail/sudo-announce/2003-April/000017.html)) your version of `sudo` is I would bet that there was not support for `sudoedit` at this time according to the changelog.

But that should not be a problem, if you have `sudo`, `sudoedit` is just the same as `sudo -e`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Our Linux version is Montavista linux 3.1 . And when I execute "sudo -e", it shows "Illegal Option". Please help!

Comment: @Bala, your version of sudo is too old. You can probably still get something with `sudo your-editor files` where your-editor is vi/vim/emacs/nano etc.

Comment: although you don't have sudoedit this blog post explain how sudoedit works and how they did before sudoedit was a thing. http://www.wingtiplabs.com/blog/posts/2013/03/13/sudoedit/

Comment: Thank a lot! Will upgrade the sudo for better functioning.